# Is there another function in pymoo that replaced MixedVariableMutation

Tags: optimization, pymoo

I'm attempting to use pymoo, but I can't seem to find the MixedVariableMutation method. Has it been deprecated? Does anyone know of a possible replacement or alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: The file was removed. The git history was rewrote.

```
git clone 
cd pymoo
git grep "MixedVariableMutation" $(git rev-list --all) | head -n 1
```

```
7b719c330ff22c10980a21a272b3a047419279c8:pymoo/operators/mixed_variable_operator.py:class MixedVariableMutation(Mutation):
```

And

```
git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 7b719c330ff22c10980a21a272b3a047419279c8
```

```
commit 7b719c330ff22c10980a21a272b3a047419279c8
Test commit before pruning files
```

Also, it seems that the history was rewrote, which is why it wasn't showing up in the changes made in the succeeding command:

```
git diff 830c9f102af09d18d45b59a4b5ffe48c043dada8
```

However, if you look up the parents of this commit, specifically, `7f538c4f9112c7d6912ff6e65fd140d1e61237a3`. You will find the change that deleted that file:
https://github.com/anyoptimization/pymoo/commit/7f538c4f9112c7d6912ff6e65fd140d1e61237a3#diff-618767a88128f4540442ba7bae9798b0db4dd670aceae294c63a23193581ea95.